# What will happen if you call interrupt() on a sleeping thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep, interrupted-exception

I have a thread, and on `run()` I call `sleep()`. What will happen if I interrupt this thread?

```
MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
          try{
             sleep(1000000);
          } catch(InterruptedException e) {//}
    }    
}
```

I want to clarify the following:

- If the thread is not yet started, calling `interrupt()` would do nothing, right?
- If the thread is started, and is now sleeping, calling `interrupt()` while sleeping will throw an `InterruptedException`; and thus, goes to `catch()` and then ends the thread, right?

Comment: What does it say in [the `Thread` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)?

Comment: The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) seems to cover this...

Comment: Trying it would also cover it.

Comment: Yeah.. why not just type the code into Java and see what happens?

Comment: "and then ends the thread": This depends entirely on where your try block is placed in the code. Think what would happen if you catch the exception inside a loop, or if after catching it you call a new function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Thread.interrupt API: *Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.*

2) In your example the interrupted thread will enter catch block then leave run method and terminate