# How to synchronize Thread.sleep and Thread.interrupt in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, thread-sleep

I would like to write a test to interrupt a thread when it is executing an interruptible call, e.g. `Thread.sleep`.

I would like to synchronize two threads: one thread calls `Thread.sleep` and another one waits till the first thread starts sleeping and interrupts it with `Thread.interrupt`.

How can I make sure that the 2nd thread interrupts the 1st one *after* it starts sleeping ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried Thread.interrupt()?

Comment: Ok. I see my question is not clear. I know I should use Thread.interrupt. The question is how to guarantee that Tread.interrupt is called _after_ Thread.sleep is invoked. I am editing the question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225579/what-will-happen-if-you-call-interrupt-on-a-sleeping-thread?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want interrupt after Thread.sleep is invoked? The interrupt is made so that it's effect is the same regardless of its invocation time, was it before or after calling to sleep(). Do you want just test it? then poll in a loop until the thread gets in [TIMED_WAITING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING) state:

```
t1.start();
while (t1.getState()!= Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) {
   Thread.sleep(10);
}
t1.interrupt();
```

Comment: Yes, this is a test. I just wanted to test this particular case. The thread state polling sounds like exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't know for sure, since for example the OS could decide to suspend the first thread right before the `Thread.sleep` statement. In practice, if you can use a small sleep in the second thread too as well as synchronization and it should be fine:

```
final CountdownLatch start = new CountdownLatch(1);

final Thread t1 = new Thread (new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        start.await();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread (new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        start.await();
        Thread.sleep(100); //wait a little to make sure that t1 is asleep
        t1.interrupt();
    }
});

t1.start();
t2.start();

Thread.sleep(100); //wait to make sure both threads are started
start.countdown();
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not like "small sleeps in practice" but I got your point.

Comment: @Michael Yes I agree and never use them either, but I don't see another way to call interrupt in the middle of sleep... Admittedly this is not a common requirement!

Comment: Not to say that it is inherently unpredictable...
In fact, now your test might not be thread-safe because it might interrupt a Thread which has just left the sleep(...) method. I wouldn't write such a test as it is likely to fail at random moments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a synchronizer and notify the interrupter thread on its lock before sleeping from the sleeper thread. Introduce a very small delay (far less than the sleep time of sleeper thread) and after wakeup issue an interrupt on the sleeper thread.

Answer (score 1):

to guarantee that 2 threads start after each other, you will need to use

```
join()
```

for example (ignoring handling the exceptions) :

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();

t1.start();
t2.join();
t2.start();
```

i didnt test the code, but here is the documentation for more information : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html